# Difference between li.append(ki) and li.append(list(ki))?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I was solving a leetcode question where we had to backtrack and figure out all combinations of digits to derive a given sum and any digit can be used unlimited number of times. I used the below python code first :

```
def combinationSum(self, candidates: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        def backtrack(candidates,start,target,li,ans):
            if target<0:
                return
            if target==0:
                ans.append(li)
            for i in range(start,len(candidates)):
                li.append(candidates[i])
                backtrack(candidates,i,target-candidates[i],li,ans)
                li.pop()
        ans = []
        backtrack(candidates,0,target,[],ans)
        return ans
```

Backtracking finds all items (even if repeated) and if target becomes 0 it appends li (list of items till which target became 0). But using above code resulted in empty lists being appended to ans variable even though I printed li and they were lists with the right answers whenever target became 0

Changing ans.append() like :

```
ans.append(list(li))
```

solved the case. But I don't understand how ? li at every time target was equal to 0 contained the list of numbers making target 0 and type of both li and list(li) was class->list. So why did  changing ans.append(li) to ans.append(list(li)) work out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ans.append(list(li))`: `list(li)` makes a **copy** of the `li`. So when you append `list(li)`, you append a new instance that is different from the original `li`.

`ans.append(li)`: just appends a **reference**, while the reference still points to the original `li`. As the original `li` instance is created in this line `backtrack(candidates,0,target,[],ans)`, all recursions of the `backtrack` functions share the same instance. As a result, you will get something like `[[], []]` as the `ans`.